# Selecionar elementos "máximos" dado um determinado critério em uma "stream"

Tags: java, java-8, stream

Tenho uma coleção de elementos que estou percorrendo em uma `stream`. Suponha que seja pegar o elemento de maior valor (inteiro) dado uma classificação (string). Essa classe é o suficiente para exemplificar meu caso:

```java
class Elemento {
  final String classificacao;
  final int valor;

  Elemento(String classificacao, int valor) {
    this.classificacao = classificacao;
    this.valor = valor;
  }

  // getters, para permitir um uso mais funcional
}
```

Preciso pegar, para os elementos de mesma "classificacao", o de maior "valor".

A minha primeira estratégia foi agrupar em um mapa `<String, List<Elemento>>` para, sobre seus valores, pegar o maior `Elemento`:

```java
Collection<Elemento> elementos = ...; // povoa os valores

elementos.stream()
  .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Elemento::getClassificacao))
  .values().stream()
  .map(l -> l.stream().max(Elemento::getValor).orElse(null))
  .filter(Objects::nonNull)
  ...; // mais
```

Tem alguma forma de fazer isso sem usar esse mapa de listas intermediário?

---

O caso real

Na verdade, o caso particular é para pegar o método mais específico dentro de uma coleção de *bridge methods*, pois aconteceu casos de "conflitos de nome" quando se implementa método genérico de uma interface genérica. No meu caso real, tenho isso para extrair os meus elementos:

```java
private static int determineSuperclass(Method ma, Method mb) {
  Class<?> ra = ma.getReturnType();
  Class<?> rb = mb.getReturnType();

  if (ra.equals(rb)) {
    return 0;
  } else if (ra.isAssignableFrom(rb)) {
    return -1;
  } else if (rb.isAssignableFrom(ra)) {
    return +1;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}

// ...

Class<T> inputClazz = ...; // povoa inputClazz
Stream.of(inputClazz.getMethods())
  .filter(m -> m.getParameterCount() == 0)
  .filter(m -> m.getName().startsWith("get"))
  .filter(m -> !Void.class.equals(m.getReturnType()))
  .filter(m -> Modifier.isPublic(m.getModifiers()))
  .filter(m -> !Modifier.isStatic(m.getModifiers()))
  .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Method::getName))
  .values().stream()
  .map(l -> l.stream().max(MyClass::determineSuperclass).orElse(null))
  .filter(Objects::nonNull)
  ...; // faço minha própria coleção
```

No meu caso, a encrenca se deu quando implementei uma interface genérica. No caso, a interface era:

```java
interface HasKey<K> {
  K getKey();
}
```

E o "problema" acontece até em classes anônimas, como:

```java
HasKey<Integer> abc = new HasKey<Integer> {
  @Override
  public Integer getKey() {
    return 1;
  }
};
```

Quando se chama `abc.getClass().getMethods()`, obtém-se dois métodos chamados `getKey()`:

```
public java.lang.Object myPackage.MyClass$1.getKey())
public java.lang.Integer myPackage.MyClass$1.getKey())
```

Mas minha intenção continua sendo como, a partir de uma uma `stream`, pegar o "maior" elemento de determinado "subgrupo", só que sem usar o mapa de listas intermediário de maneira explícita.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> <sup><sub>*A versão inicial da pergunta pedia:*</sub></sup> Tem alguma forma de fazer isso sem usar esse `Map` intermediário de maneira explícita?

Daria para usar [`collectingAndThen`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#collectingAndThen-java.util.stream.Collector-java.util.function.Function-):

```
Stream<Elemento> stream = elementos.stream().collect(
    Collectors.collectingAndThen(
        Collectors.groupingBy(Elemento::getClassificacao),
        map -> map.values().stream()
                  .map(l -> l.stream().max(Comparator.comparing(Elemento::getValor)).orElse(null))
                  .filter(Objects::nonNull)));
```

Primeiro ele aplica o `groupingBy`, e depois o resultado é passado para o *finisher* (o lambda que é passado como segundo parâmetro). No caso, ele recebe o resultado do `groupingBy` (o `Map`) e extrai o elemento de maior valor para cada classificação.

No fim, é criado um `Map`, mas podemos considerar que é de maneira "implícita" (podemos?). Talvez haja alguma otimização interna nesse método, mas pode ser que não, e no fim dê no mesmo. Não sei, eu não vi tanta diferença assim para a sua solução, e acho até que a minha ficou um pouco mais confusa de ler e entender.

O resultado é uma `Stream` de `Elemento`, que você pode continuar usando da maneira que precisar.

---

#### Evitando o mapa de listas

<sup><sub>*Após a edição, foi pedido para eliminar o mapa de listas.*</sub></sup>

Para evitar o mapa de listas, você pode coletar usando [`Collectors.toMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-):

```
Map<String, Integer> results = elementos.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Elemento::getClassificacao, Elemento::getValor, Math::max));
```

O primeiro parâmetro define qual será a chave do map (no caso, a classificação), e o segundo parâmetro, o respectivo valor (no caso, o `valor` do elemento). O terceiro parâmetro define o critério de desempate, caso haja mais de um valor para a mesma chave (usei [`Math::max`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#max-int-int-), assim ele pega o maior `valor`).

O resultado é um `Map` cujas chaves são as classificações, e os valores são o maior `valor` daquela classificação.

Comment: Sendo sincero, ainda não gostei =/ Parece mais funcional, mas ainda preciso fazer uma chama a `Map.values()` dentro do lambda. Logo, ainda tem um dedo explícito do `Map`. Talvez um coletor próprio resolva? Mas, sim, está menos explícito o uso do `Map`...

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Tudo bem, eu também não gostei muito da minha solução :-) Talvez um coletor próprio seja o caminho (só não sugeri porque, sinceramente, eu nunca precisei criar um - se sobrar um tempo eu tento e atualizo a resposta). Mas dentro desse coletor vc teria que usar um algoritmo que não crie o map, senão não vai adiantar nada também :-)

Comment: Pois é, mas pelo menos não vai ser necessário um mapa de lista... Acho que meu maior incômodo é esse, só não sei como realmente expressar isso dentro do contexto

Comment: Editei a questão para deixar claro que é mapa de lista que me incomoda. Obrigado por me ajudar a enxergar mais corretamente minha dúvida

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Atualizei a resposta. Como é a primeira vez que uso o método `collect` com 3 parâmetros, pode não ser a melhor solução, mas pelo menos consegui eliminar o map de listas

Comment: Tem um erro na solução 2 (`.collect` com 3 argumentos). O `putAll` fará com que eventualmente algum máximo seja sobrescrito. Deve ter um novo método default de `Map` como um `putIf` ou alguma outra coisa semelhante

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado É mesmo, faltou testar melhor... Bom, quando puder eu arrumo (talvez eu consiga ver isso hj, mas o mais provável é só amanhã), obrigado por avisar :-) Mas e a terceira solução? Acho que ela já trata melhor as entradas duplicadas (mas não testei ainda)

Comment: a terceira parece certa =]

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Fiz alguns testes mas não foram muito conclusivos, não consegui reproduzir o erro que vc menciona, mas se vc disse que está errado eu acredito :-) - De qualquer forma, achei melhor retirar a solução 2 e deixar somente a 3, que pelos testes que fiz ela parece funcionar melhor mesmo.

Answer (score 4):

Porque você não usa o [método `Method.isBridge()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#isBridge()) para te ajudar?

Aqui vai o MCVE:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.Modifier;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class MyClass {

    public static boolean isPublicDeclaredGetter(Method m) {
        int mod = m.getModifiers();
        Class<?> returnType = m.getReturnType();
        String name = m.getName();
        boolean is = name.startsWith("is");
        boolean get = name.startsWith("get");
        int suffixIndex = get ? 3 : 2;

        return returnType != void.class
                && returnType != Void.class
                && !"is".equals(name)
                && !"get".equals(name)
                && Modifier.isPublic(mod)
                && !Modifier.isStatic(mod)
                && !m.isBridge()
                && m.getParameterCount() == 0
                && (get || (is && (returnType == boolean.class || returnType == Boolean.class)))
                && Character.isUpperCase(name.substring(suffixIndex, suffixIndex + 1).charAt(0));
    }

    public interface A<X> {
        public X getFoo1();
        public X getFoo2();
        public int getBar1();
    }

    public interface B extends A<String> {
        public String getFoo2();
        public String getBar2();
        public boolean isOk();
        public static int getBad1() { return 0; }
        public void getBad2();
        public String isBad3();
        public int getBad4(int x);
        public String getulio();
        public String isam();
        public int get();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Class<?> inputClazz = B.class;
        Stream.of(inputClazz.getMethods())
            .filter(MyClass::isPublicDeclaredGetter)
            .forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Como você pode ter percebido, coloquei a regra para definir se é um getter no método `isPublicDeclaredGetter`. O motivo é que do jeito que você fez inicialmente, um método chamado `isVisible` não seria considerado um getter enquanto que `getulio` seria. E um método chamado apenas `get` também seria considerado como um getter. Além disso, objetos do tipo `Class` podem ser comparados com `==`, não precisando usar o `equals`. Por fim, observe o `isBridge()` lá.

Eis a saída:

```
public abstract boolean MyClass$B.isOk()
public abstract java.lang.String MyClass$B.getFoo2()
public abstract java.lang.String MyClass$B.getBar2()
public abstract java.lang.Object MyClass$A.getFoo1()
public abstract int MyClass$A.getBar1()
```

Observe que nenhum método se repetiu, que onde havia colisões de nomes, o mais específico foi escolhido e que nenhum método indesejado apareceu.

Comment: "_Porque você não usa o método Method.isBridge()?_" R: ignorância de minha parte =)

Comment: Aproveitando, não sabia que dava pra usar `boolean.class`, só conhecia o `Boolean.class`

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Sim, dá. Ele produz o objeto `Class` que aponta para o tipo primitivo. Já usando `Boolean`, você referencia a classe empacotadora. E o mais interessante é o `void.class`.

Comment: Sobre usar o `Class.equals`, é [trauma](https://gitlab.com/totalcross/TotalCross/issues/590#note_210695782) mesmo...

Comment: Você resolveu meu problema natural (o X), mas acho que consegui deixar claro meu problema artificial (o Y). Por isso, vou dar uma recompensa quando for possível, mas aceitarei a resposta do hkotsubo

Comment: Sua resposta me inspirou uma dúvida: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/408621/64969