# O que são métodos "bridge" em Java?

Tags: java, característica-linguagem, jvm

Recentemente, tive um [problema com métodos *bridge*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/408497/64969), o que ocasional numa excelente [resposta do Victor Stafusa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/408525/64969).

Porém, agora percebo que não sei o porquê desse método *bridge* ter sido criado, nem tampouco o que significa um método ser ou não *bridge*.

Então, minhas dúvidas sobre o assunto:

- O que é um método *bridge*?
- Como criar métodos *bridge*?
- Por que surgiram métodos *bridge* na história do Java?
- Quais problemas eles resolvem?
- Esses problemas, eram da linguagem Java ou referentes a alguma limitação da JVM?
- Essa característica tem algum paralelo em alguma outra linguagem? Qual linguagem? Qual o problema nessa outra linguagem é resolvido com isso?
- Outras linguagens que tem como alvo padrão a JVM, precisam estar alertas à existência desses métodos?

Comment: Pra ir ajudando enquanto O Victor não vem responder :) https://stackoverflow.com/q/5007357/221800. Nem está bom lá, acho que aqui terá uma resposta muito melhor. Só releia o primeiro parágrafo :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> - O que é um método bridge?
> - Como criar métodos bridge?
> - Por que surgiram métodos bridge na história do Java?
> - Quais problemas eles resolvem?
> - Esses problemas, eram da linguagem Java ou referentes a alguma limitação da JVM?

Os métodos bridge são sintéticos, ou seja, quem os introduz é o compilador. Eles foram introduzidos no Java 5 e a finalidade deles é fazer com que a covariância dos tipos genéricos funcione no nível da JVM.

Por exemplo:

```
class A<T> {
    public int foo(T x) {
        return 42;
    }
}

class B extends A<String> {
    @Override
    public int foo(String x) {
        return 53;
    }
}
```

Observe que o método `foo` da classe `B` sobrescreve o `foo` da classe `A`. No entanto, os parâmetros são diferentes.

No Java, um método da subclasse/subinterface sobrescreve outro quando: (a) tem o mesmo nome e (b) parâmetros do mesmo tipo. Com o advento dos tipos genéricos, saber quando ocorre sobrescrita é mais difícil do que antes deles, e para piorar, a JVM não tem os tipos genéricos em tempo de execução devido ao *type-erasure* (apagamento).

Devido ao *type-erasure*, o que a JVM enxerga na classe `A` em tempo de execução é isso:

```
    public int foo(Object x) {
        return 42;
    }
```

A razão disso é que o tipo genérico `T` é apagado para o seu tipo base, ou seja, `Object`. No caso de um tipo genérico `<X extends Y>`, devido ao *type erasure*, todas as referências do tipo genérico `X` são vistas pela JVM como ocorrências do tipo `Y`.

Para resolver essa incompatibilidade entre os tipos de parâmetros dos métodos no nível da JVM em tempo de execução, a solução é que o compilador crie um método sintético na classe `B` assim:

```
    public int foo(Object x) {
        return foo((String) x);
    }
```

Há ainda outras complicações devido ao tipo de retorno. Pois na JVM, para que haja sobrescrita de métodos, não apenas o tipo dos parâmetros tem que ser igual, mas o tipo de retorno também. Novamente, isso é resolvido com métodos bridge introduzidos pelo compilador que fazem *casts* também com o valor de retorno. Por exemplo:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class Exemplo {

    class C<X, Y> {
        public X foo1(Y x) {
            return null;
        }

        public int foo2(Y x) {
            return 42;
        }

        public X foo3(int x) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    class D extends C<String, Integer> {
        @Override
        public String foo1(Integer x) {
            return "abc";
        }

        @Override
        public int foo2(Integer x) {
            return 53;
        }

        @Override
        public String foo3(int x) {
            return "xyz";
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Métodos de C:");
        for (Method m : C.class.getMethods()) {
            if (m.getDeclaringClass() != Object.class) System.out.println(m);
        }
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Métodos de D:");
        for (Method m : D.class.getMethods()) {
            if (m.getDeclaringClass() != Object.class) System.out.println(m);
        }
    }
}
```

Observe a saída:

```
Métodos de C:
public java.lang.Object Exemplo$C.foo1(java.lang.Object)
public int Exemplo$C.foo2(java.lang.Object)
public java.lang.Object Exemplo$C.foo3(int)

Métodos de D:
public java.lang.Object Exemplo$D.foo1(java.lang.Object)
public java.lang.String Exemplo$D.foo1(java.lang.Integer)
public int Exemplo$D.foo2(java.lang.Object)
public int Exemplo$D.foo2(java.lang.Integer)
public java.lang.String Exemplo$D.foo3(int)
public java.lang.Object Exemplo$D.foo3(int)
```

Perceba que na classe `D`, todos os três métodos `foo1`, `foo2` e `foo3` são duplicados. As duplicatas que usam os tipos bases dos genéricos (`Object` neste caso) são os métodos bridge. Observe também que os tipos genéricos que aparecem para a classe `C` foram apagados para os seus tipos base.

Referência oficial:

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bridgeMethods.html

> - Essa característica tem algum paralelo em alguma outra linguagem? Qual linguagem? Qual o problema nessa outra linguagem é resolvido com isso?

Desconheço, mas não posso afirmar que não exista. No caso de linguagens com tipagem dinâmica tais como Python, Javascript e em grande parte (mas não de todo) o PHP, os métodos bridge não teriam nenhum sentido de existir, mas em linguagens com tipagem estática, pode ser que sim. No fundo, os métodos bridge são uma gambiarra para resolver uma limitação da JVM, e portanto, faz pouco sentido que tal coisa exista na maioria das demais linguagens de programação.

> - Outras linguagens que tem como alvo padrão a JVM, precisam estar alertas à existência desses métodos?

Sim, mas em casos bem raros. Mesmo em Java, raramente os métodos bridge causam algum problema. Isso só se torna um problema quando você está fazendo alguma operação com *reflection* e a presença dos métodos bridge acaba lhe atrapalhando, exatamente como você fez [na sua pergunta anterior](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/408497/132). Mas esse tipo de circunstância é algo bastante incomum.

Comment: Puta gambi, mas eu já imaginava isso :D