# Como funciona a criação de um Proxy por debaixo dos panos?

Tags: java, característica-linguagem, jvm

Tenho me divertido bastante criando proxies de interfaces em Java. Por exemplo, o seguinte *proxy* foi necessário no SQLDroid para fazer funcionar a versão 5.2.4 do Flyway (e também para pegar o *path* do arquivo criado pelo driver):

```java
// interface para pegar o path do arquivo

public interface DataSourceHasFilename extends DataSource {

    String getDbFilename();
}

// classe que tem o código do proxy


public class ProxyDataSource {

    private final DroidDataSource ds;
    private final DataSourceHasFilename dshf;

    public ProxyDataSource(DroidDataSource ds) {
        this.ds = ds;
        String dbFilename = "/data/data/" + ds.getPackageName() + "/" + ds.getDatabaseName() + ".db";

        dshf = (DataSourceHasFilename) Proxy.newProxyInstance(this.getClass().getClassLoader(), new Class[] {DataSourceHasFilename.class }, (proxy, method, args) -> {
            switch (method.getName()) {
            case "getDbFilename":
                return dbFilename;
            case "getConnection":
                return connWrapper((Connection) method.invoke(ds, args));
            }
            return method.invoke(ds, args);
        });
    }

    public DataSourceHasFilename asDataSourceHasFilename() {
        return dshf;
    }

    private Connection connWrapper(Connection c) {
        return (Connection) Proxy.newProxyInstance(this.getClass().getClassLoader(), new Class[] { Connection.class }, (proxy, method, args) -> {
            switch (method.getName()) {
            case "getMetaData":
            return metadataWrapper((DatabaseMetaData) method.invoke(c, args));
            }
            return method.invoke(c, args);
        });
    }

    public DatabaseMetaData metadataWrapper(DatabaseMetaData dmd) {
        return (DatabaseMetaData) Proxy.newProxyInstance(this.getClass().getClassLoader(), new Class[] { DatabaseMetaData.class }, (proxy, method, args) -> {
            switch (method.getName()) {
            case "getDatabaseMajorVersion":
            return 3;
            case "getDatabaseMinorVersion":
            return 7;
            }
            return method.invoke(dmd, args);
        });
    }
}
```

A criação do *proxy* se dá chamando [`java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html#newProxyInstance-java.lang.ClassLoader-java.lang.Class:A-java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler-). Ele cria um objeto com as interfaces passadas na chamada ao método `newProxyInstance` e que, de algum modo, todas as chamadas feitas aos métodos dessa interface são delegados ao `InvocationHandler`.

Então, como que, por debaixo dos panos, o Java cria esse objeto?

Ele precisa de algum modificador para indicar que é proxy?

Por que ele não cria métodos *bridge* quando implementa uma interface que estende uma interface genérica, mas sim 2 métodos concretos distintos*?

> *: consegui isso pegando a interface `B` [desta resposta do Victor Stafusa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/408640/64969) e a instanciando como *proxy*:
>
> ```java
> Proxy.newProxyInstance(Main.class.getClassLoader(),
>     new Class[] { B.class },
>     (Object proxy, Method method, Object[] argsM) -> {
>             switch (method.getName()) {
>             case "getBar1":
>                 return 1;
>             case "isOk":
>                 return true;
>             }
>             return null;
>         });
> ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Então, como que, por debaixo dos panos, o Java cria esse objeto?

Observe que o `newProxyInstance` recebe como primeiro parâmetro um `ClassLoader` e como segundo, um array de interfaces. O que ele vai fazer é criar uma classe nova que implemente todas as interfaces dadas. A classe é criada construindo-se os seus bytecodes e então usando o `ClassLoader` dado para carregá-la na memória.

No entanto, e a implementação dos métodos dessa interface? Isso fica por conta do `InvocationHandler`, que é o lambda que você passa como terceiro parâmetro. Todos os métodos simplesmente o invocam e lá você decide o que fazer. Nenhum método bridge é necessário nesse caso.

Por fim, depois que essa classe tiver sido criada, ela é instanciada e um objeto dela é retornado.

Ou seja, vamos supor que você faça isso:

```
Object x = Proxy.newProxyInstance(
        algumClassLoader,
        new Class<?>[] {Runnable.class, Readable.clas},
        algumLambdaAqui)
```

Ele vai criar uma classe em tempo de execução que seja algo parecido com isso:

```
public class Proxy$1 extends Proxy implements Runnable, Readable {
    public Proxy$1(InvocationHandler h) {
        super(h);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        h.invoke(this, getClass().getMethod("run"), new Object[] {});
    }

    @Override
    public int read(CharBuffer cb) {
        return (int) h.invoke(this, getClass().getMethod("read", CharBuffer.class), new Object[] { cb });
    }
}
```

E então te retornar uma instância desse objeto. [O `h` é `InvocationHandler` que é armazenado num campo `protected` com esse nome na classe `Proxy`.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html#h)

> Ele precisa de algum modificador para indicar que é proxy?

Não. Um método chamado `newProxyInstance` em uma classe chamada `Proxy` não teria sentido precisar de algo para indicar que o objeto retornado é um `Proxy`, não é mesmo?

Se você precisa saber se algum objeto qualquer é um proxy, você pode utilizar o [método `isProxyClass(Class<?>)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html#isProxyClass(java.lang.Class)) assim:

```
Object foo = ...;
boolean isProxy = Proxy.isProxyClass(foo.getClass());
```

> Por que ele não cria métodos bridge quando implementa uma interface que estende uma interface genérica, mas sim 2 métodos concretos distintos*?

O mecanismo de `Proxy` foi concebido no Java 1.3, e portanto é mais antigo do que os métodos bridge do Java 5. Pode-se argumentar que todos os métodos são implementados como algo semelhante ao que os métodos bridge fazem, apenas delegando a chamada a alguma outra coisa.

Para que métodos bridge fizessem sentido, seria necessário que houvesse algum tipo de covariância entre diferentes implementações. No entanto, você não pode fazer o seu proxy implementar algo como `Comparator<Integer>` porque não há `Comparator<Integer>` como classe, apenas há `Comparator`. No entanto, você pode contornar isso declarando `interface MeuComparator extends Comparator<Integer>`.

Além disso, todos os métodos das interfaces (mesmo os que estiverem marcados como `default`) vão ser sobrescritos no proxy pelo código que faz a chamada ao `InvocationHandler`, **inclusive os métodos bridge e os métodos default da interface**.

Aqui vai um exemplo que mostra que o método bridge também é sobrescrito pelo `Proxy`:

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.Proxy;

public class Exemplo2 {

    interface MeuComparator extends Comparator<Integer> {
        @Override
        public int compare(Integer x, Integer y);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Comparator a = new MeuComparator() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Integer x, Integer y) {
                return 42;
            }
        };
        System.out.println(a.compare((Object) 5, (Object) 7));

        System.out.println("Métodos de MeuComparator:");
        for (Method m : MeuComparator.class.getMethods()) {
            if ("compare".equals(m.getName())) System.out.println(m);
        }
        System.out.println();

        MeuComparator proxy = (MeuComparator) Proxy.newProxyInstance(
                Exemplo2.class.getClassLoader(),
                new Class<?>[] {MeuComparator.class},
                (o, m, p) -> {
                    System.out.println(m);
                    return 27;
                });

        proxy.compare(Integer.valueOf(3), Integer.valueOf(4));

        // Usa o tipo bruto para enganar o verificador de tipos do compilador.
        Comparator c = proxy;
        c.compare("bar", "foo");
    }
}
```

Eis a saída:

```
42
Métodos de MeuComparator:
public abstract int Exemplo2$MeuComparator.compare(java.lang.Integer,java.lang.Integer)
public default int Exemplo2$MeuComparator.compare(java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object)

public abstract int Exemplo2$MeuComparator.compare(java.lang.Integer,java.lang.Integer)
public default int Exemplo2$MeuComparator.compare(java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object)
```